# Sequence constructed from the previous element of the Sequence and another Sequence

Tags: f#, sequence

For learning purposes I am trying out running a simulation as a sequence with F#. Starting from a sequence of random numbers, map is a straightforward way to generate a sequence of states if the states do not depend on the previous states. Where I run into a problem is when I try to do something like:
State(i+1) = F (State(i), random number)
I managed to get something working by using unfold, passing in the random generator along the lines of

```
  let unfold (day:State,rnd:Random) =
    let rand = rnd.NextDouble()
    let nextDay = NextState day rand
    Some (nextDay, (nextDay, rnd))
```

However, at least to my inexperienced eyes, something about passing around the Random instance seems fishy. Is there a way to achieve something similar but passing in a sequence of random numbers, rather than the generator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your hunch about passing around a `Random` instance as being fishy is fair: when mutable state is useful it's a good idea to isolate it, so that you benifit from purity as much as possible.

We can isolate the state here by creating a sequence which yields a *different* set of random numbers upon each iteration

```
open System
let rndSeq = 
    seq {
        //note that by putting rnd inside seq expression here, we ensure that each iteration of the sequence
        //yields a different sequnce of random numbers
        let rnd = new Random()
        while true do yield rnd.NextDouble()
    }
```

then, you can use `Seq.scan` to iterate the random sequence by mapping elements using a function which is informed by the previous element which was mapped.

```
let runSimulation inputSeq initialState =
    inputSeq
    |> Seq.scan 
        (fun (previousState:State) (inputElement:float) -> NextState previousState inputElement) 
        initialState

runSimulation rndSeq initialState //run the simulation using a random sequence of doubles greater than or equal to 0.0 and less than 1
```

You can see as an added bonus here that your simulated input and simulation implementation are no longer bound together, you can run your simulation using any input sequence.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for, in terms of intent: that is, separating the input sequence from the sequence of states.

Answer (score 4):

I'd agree with BrokenGlass that using a global `Random` instance feels allright in this case. This is a reasonably localized use of mutable state, so it shouldn't be confusing.

As an alternative to `unfold`, you can consider writing the computation explicitly:

```
let simulationStates = 
    let rnd = new Random()
    let rec generate (day:State) = seq {
        let rand = rnd.NextDouble()
        let nextDay = NextState day rand 
        yield nextDay
        yield! generate nextDay }
    generate InitialState
```

Note that the `rnd` value is local variable with a scope limited only to the definition of `simulationStates`. This is quite nice way to keep mutable state separate from the rest of the program.

The version using `unfold` is probably more succinct; this one may be easier to read, so it depends on your personal style preferences.

Answer (score 1):

Might be against the spirit, but I would just use a global Random instance in this case - alternatively you could define a sequence of random numbers like this:

```
let randomNumbers = 
    seq  {
            let rnd = new Random();
            while true do
                yield rnd.NextDouble();
         }
```

Comment: I am actually using more or less that code to create a Sequence of random numbers. What I would like to do is to pass that sequence as an input to the simulation, i.e. pass randomNumbers as an argument, rather than the instance of Random().